# Extending eclipse plugin : How to enable and disable menu?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I want enable my 2nd and 7th menu if the process for first menu is complete. I want to enable my 3rd and 7th menu if process for 2nd menu is complete and so on. I have seven menu. At very first only first menu should be active and remaining should be disable and at second time if 1st process is complete then only 1st menu, 2nd menu and 7th menu should be enabled.

I am not getting how should I make changes in my `plugin.xml` in order to work as I am expecting. Here is my `plugin.xml` code. Please help me and thank you in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">

      <menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu?after=additions">
            <menu id = "documentation.handlers.Documentation"
             label = "Documentation">
               <command id="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler" 
               commandId="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler">
                </command>
                <command id="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler1" 
               commandId="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler1">
                </command>
                <command id="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler2" 
               commandId="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler2">
                </command>  
                <command id="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler3" 
               commandId="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler3">
                </command>  
                <command id="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler4" 
               commandId="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler4">
                </command>  
                <command id="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler4" 
               commandId="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler5">
                </command>  
                <command id="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler4" 
               commandId="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler6">
                </command>  
                </menu>
      </menuContribution>
      <menuContribution 
        locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar?after=additions">
         <toolbar id="documentation.handlers.sampleToolbar">
         <command id="documentation.handlers.sampleCommand" 
          commandId="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler">
           </command>
           <command id="documentation.handlers.sampleCommand" 
          commandId="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler1">
           </command>
           <command id="documentation.handlers.sampleCommand" 
          commandId="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler2">
           </command>
           <command id="documentation.handlers.sampleCommand" 
          commandId="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler3">
           </command>
          <command id="documentation.handlers.sampleCommand" 
          commandId="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler4">
           </command>
          <command id="documentation.handlers.sampleCommand" 
          commandId="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler5">
           </command>
          <command id="documentation.handlers.sampleCommand" 
          commandId="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler6">
           </command>
          </toolbar>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>

  <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <command
            id="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler"
            name="Project Descritpion">
      </command>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers"
         id = "documentation.handlers">
      <handler
            class="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler"
            commandId="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler">
      </handler>
   </extension>

    <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <command
            id="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler1"
            name="Fact Finding Techniques">
      </command>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers"
         id = "documentation.handlers">
      <handler
            class="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler1"
            commandId="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler1">
      </handler>
   </extension>

   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <command
            id="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler2"
            name="Feasibility Study">
      </command>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers"
         id = "documentation.handlers">
      <handler
            class="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler2"
            commandId="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler2">
      </handler>
   </extension>

    <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <command
            id="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler3"
            name="Technical Requirement">
      </command>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers"
         id = "documentation.handlers">
      <handler
            class="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler3"
            commandId="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler3">
      </handler>
   </extension>

   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <command
            id="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler4"
            name="Open Documentation">
      </command>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers"
         id = "documentation.handlers">
      <handler
            class="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler4"
            commandId="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler4">
      </handler>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <command
            id="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler5"
            name="UML Diagrams">
      </command>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers"
         id = "documentation.handlers">
      <handler
            class="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler5"
            commandId="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler5">
      </handler>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <command
            id="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler6"
            name="Database Development">
      </command>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers"
         id = "documentation.handlers">
      <handler
            class="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler6"
            commandId="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler6">
      </handler>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "the process for the first menu is complete."? Do you mean the menuitem is clicked or the Handler of the Comamnd has finished, or do you have a long running process in the back that has to be finished first?

Comment: The process for the first finished means on first form I am accepting information from user. Once user fill information I am generating ProjectDecription.xml file which contain data accepted by user. Once the file is generated means process for 1st handler is complete. On 2nd handler I am again accepting information from user and merging it to ProjectDescription.xml and similarly for other. So I want on first time only 1st menu should be enable and all other disable. and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You would do this with an `enabledWhen` expression on the `handler` for each command. It sounds like you will probably have to use a property tester to define a custom test for the enabled when expression.

Use the `org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters` to define a property tester, something like:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters">
  <propertyTester
    id="documentation.propertytester"
    type="java.lang.Object"
    namespace="documentation"
    properties="handler1enabled,handler2enabled,handler3enabled.. and so on ..."
    class="documentation.PropertyTester">
  </propertyTester>
</extension>
```

You then code a `documention.PropertyTester` class to do the property tests.

You can then use it in your enabled when expression like this:

```xml
<handler
        class="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler5"
        commandId="documentation.handlers.SampleHandler5">
     <enabledWhen>
         <test
              property="namespace.handler5enabled">
         </test>
     </enabledWhen>
</handler>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you please write sample code at which extension point I need to add this code it'll be more convenient for me. Because I am not getting where to add this code in plugin.xml Can you please post code. Thank in advance

Comment: The handler is the org.eclipse.ui.handlers that you already have, you just have to add the enabledWhen part to those.

Comment: @user3497146 greg gave you all you might need. If you are still unsure how to use Propertytesters try this detailed tutorial: http://www.robertwloch.net/2011/01/eclipse-tips-tricks-property-testers-with-command-core-expressions/

Comment: Thank you for both gerg-449 and Calon. Your help is really useful for me. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Hey greg-449 I followed your instruction but when I put only <enableWhen> in my handler its hiding particular menu. But the problem is now I want to enable them if according to condition means want to enable 2nd handler if handler1's process is finished. I am not getting how to write this condition. Could you please help me to do that??